# Android: Send Extras (ArrayList) to any Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I have 3 activities, First Activity(Main), Middle Activity, and Final Activity. Currently, I'm sending Serializable Arraylists via Intent. Which works great when I create an intent to start Final Activity from within First Activity, although it skips over Middle Activity which needs to be displayed. The problem I'm running into is that all of the data originates in First Activity, and I can't seem to send it from First Activity, to Final Activity, and still display Middle Activity. I'm wondering if I should try to send the Arraylists via SharedPreferences instead?

```
 List<String> proStrings = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.SendButton:

            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MiddleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("proGolferArray", String.valueOf(i));


            //CREATE BUNDLE AND ADD ARRAYLIST AS SERIALIZABLE
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("PROGOLFER", (Serializable) proStrings);

            //START NEW INTENT WITH ARRAYLIST BUNDLE PASSED IN
            intentFinal = new Intent(this, FinalActivity.class);
            intentFinal.putExtra("KEY", bundle);

            startActivity(intent);
            //startActivity(intentFinal);

//this doesn't look right, I must be doing this wrong....

            break;
    }

}
```

}

From MiddleActivity, I start the FinalActivity, but when I do, the data from the ArrayList in First Activity doesn't appear in FinalActivity at all. Is there a way to start 'finalIntent' from Middle Activity so that the data is sent to FinalActivity properly?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to display MiddleActivity first, and then display finalActivity??

Comment: Yes exactly, I can't seem to find a way to access my arraylist in final. I have been researching for a few hours and found that there is a way to pass the arraylist via Shared Preferences... but I'm still trying to figure out how to implement it. @JoelMin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to display MiddleActivity and then FinalActivity, try the following?

1. Launch MiddleActivity from FirstActivity along with the arraylist
2. Get the arraylist in onCreate() of MiddleActivity
3. Start FinalActivity from MiddleActivity along with the arraylist retrieved in step 2

And by the way the code you posted in the question is wrong. You should attach the bundle to `intent` and not `finalintent`